# How to write unit test for these type of methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, gremlin

I'm new to unit testing . How to write unit test for these type of methods?

```
 private boolean fn(Vertex vertex) {
        return vertex.id().toString().split(":").length > 1;
    }
```

Here Vertex is the element of gremlin query . 
I have tried to create instance of graph and pass a new Vertex object to the function but not working .
i.e

```
Vertex vertex = (Vertex) graphTraversalSource.addV("Test").property(id,"Profile:TEST");
```

Can anyone suggest the ways to test these types of method?

Comment: Simple answer, you don't. You only write unit tests for public (or protected) methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked your question about "unit testing" but your question really seems to be about why:

```
Vertex vertex = (Vertex) graphTraversalSource.addV("Test").property(id,"Profile:TEST");
```

doesn't let you create a `Vertex` that you can test. I'd say the most obvious problem is that you didn't [iterate your traversal](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration) in any way. In this case you need to call `next()`:

```
Vertex vertex = (Vertex) graphTraversalSource.addV("Test").property(id,"Profile:TEST").next();
```

Of course, for your `fn(Vertex)` function that you want to test, I don't see much point in creating an actual `Vertex` in a graph database - you could instead just use `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertex` and do:

```
Vertex vertex = new DetachedVertex("Profile:TEST", "Test", null);
```

and then pass that to your function to test.

Comment: "Vertex vertex = new DetachedVertex("Profile:TEST", "Test");  " . This has only protected access , so how to use it? @stephen mallette

Comment: sorry - the third parameter is `null`.

Comment: How this syntax of yours is even working ? "Vertex" and "DetachedVertex" are two different types of object .

Comment: `Vertex` is a Java interface and `DetachedVertex` implements it: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/util/detached/DetachedVertex.html