# How to mock these types of query?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, gremlin

I'm new in unit testing . I've to test a public method which uses the following private method .

```
     public void f1({some parameters}){
             List<Vertex> rVertex = fn(vertexId, graphTraversalSource,2);
            for (Vertex vertex : resultVertex) {
                if (checkingForAProperty(vertex.id().toString())) {
                     // some operations
                }
            }
         }


    private List<Vertex> fn(String v, GraphTraversalSource g, int i) {
        return g.V(v).repeat(in().dedup().simplePath()).until(loops().is(i)).toList();
      }
```

I thought of the following (terrible) approach (Assume g is mocked here ) :

```
when (g.V(v)).then(X);
when (X.repeat(any)).then(Y);
when (Y.until(any)).then(Z);
```

But I could'nt decide how to do that . Any suggestions to do this will be really helpful.

Comment: Why does g need to be mocked?

Comment: Because I thought , I do'nt need to make actual connection and make queries here.

Comment: Ah, do those methods have slow side effects? What's the behaviour you're trying to test here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Overall , the code does the query and performs code changes (implementation part) . So I need the manipulate the "fn" method to test the implementation part .

Comment: You may want to take a step back and describe/think about your overall testing methodology for graph traversals. What is it that you want to really verify? Perhaps creating a small TinkerGraph with known test data and verifying against that would be more meaningful for example in this case.  You may also want to take a look at the way the Apache TinkerPop tests are written.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Yes . Valid points . But in my case creating a new TinkerGraph is not really an option.

Comment: Can you expand on what your case is? The previous two questions asked got closed I suspect because people are not clear what exactly you need to be verifying.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154074/how-to-write-unit-test-for-these-type-of-methods

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037521/how-to-write-unit-test-for-this-method-in-java      

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154074/how-to-write-unit-test-for-these-type-of-methods

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037521/how-to-write-unit-test-for-this-method-in-java

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I have given an overview of my case here .

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using *deep stubs*:

```java
GraphTraversalSource g = mock(GraphTraversalSource.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(g.V(any()).repeat(any()).until(any()).thenReturn(z);
```

However, bear in mind that deep stubbing should be used rarely (see [wiki](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#can-i-stub-chained-getters)):

> This sort of stubbing, e.g. mock to return mock, to return mock, etc. should be used very sporadically, *ideally never*. It clearly points out violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). You don't want to mess with Demeter. Since you have been warned check out Mockito [deep stubs](http://www.javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS).